# Show multiline aliases in zsh with line breaks as in bash

Tags: zsh, alias, zshrc

When printing all available aliases on stdout via command `alias` a multiline alias in bash will printed with the line breaks but it does not in zsh.

Example with the identical multiline alias definition for bash `.bash_aliases` and zsh `.zsh_aliases`:

```
alias hello='
        echo "Hello"
        echo "beautiful"
        echo "world"'
```

When the alias `hello` is executed the result is the same on both shells.

But when comparing the printout of the definiton via `alias hello` on stdout...

- in bash the output is:

```
alias hello='
        echo "Hello"
        echo "beautiful"
        echo "world"'
```

- whereas in zsh the output looks like this:

```
hello=$'\n        echo "Hello"\n        echo "beautiful"\n        echo "world"'
```

Why is the `\n` in zsh not printed as new line and the tabulator `\t` not respected like in bash`s stdout?

I tried several escaping but without success.

Comment: There's no particular reason why either shell should show the output in either way.

Comment: What makes you think that the output should be the same? Even a new bash version could decide to change the format. Actually, the zsh way has the advantage that when you dump your aliases with `alias`, each definition takes up only one line, which makes it easier to post-process the output in a pipe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the print built-in to display the text with newlines:

```bash
print "$(alias)"
```

e.g.

```bash
> print "$(alias hello)"
hello=$'
        echo "Hello"
        echo "beautiful"
        echo "world"'
```

---

It's usually preferable to use a function for anything with multiple lines rather than an alias. With a function you have fewer worries about quoting and a generally easier-to-follow syntax:

```bash
hello2() {
  print Hello
  print beautiful
  print world
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I will consider to use the print "$(alias)" command instead. Yes it is totally correct to usually prefer using a function alias for multiline definitions.

But the function aliases will not printet on stdout when using the "alias" command.
Is there a way to show or print also the function alieases on stdout?

Comment: The `functions` command will list the normalized code for functions; `functions -x2` (or another number) can be used to change the indentation size. `zsh` also has [associative arrays](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/366700) named `aliases` and `functions` that can be handy for getting [information](https://superuser.com/a/684256) about what is defined.

Comment: Thats it what I have been loking for. But might there a possibility to make it more precise and list only the custom functions that are for example defined inside of .zsh_aliases?

Comment: Not really; the only readily available method to filter the list is by name, as described in the 'information' link above. Anything else would require some custom setup (and a separate question).